# How to create CakePHP Common Controller Logic

Tags: php, html, cakephp, controller

i am currently working on a website. I have made the code such that the contents of the footer is dynamic i.e, it is fetched from database. Now i want to write single code of controller logic for that and use it in the rest of all pages...any help??

Comment: Vague question like that are better suited on IRC or the google group. Anways, check out [**components**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) and [**elements**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements).

Comment: showing what you're currently doing would permit directing you to what you _should_ be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply fetch the data from one helper function like showFooter().
And you can use it every layout files